# Sum attribute values based on previous attribute value

Tags: qgis

How to add previous attribute value to the next attribute value?
I have a linelayer and a corresponding pointlayer. The points contain a demand value. I can add that value to the lines. But I want to simulate a water distribution network, so I want to sum the demand in the line based on previous lines.

The points each have a demand of 5 (red). Starting on the left. the first line should have a demand of 5, next line of 10, 15, 20 , the last line should have a demand value of 25. How can I do this?

Eventually i want to apply this problem to a more difficult infrastructure where the red dot is the end point.(see 2nd image)

data:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-aNFSenH9fl7S9s535gu62cP68ZTNe2u?usp=sharing

[image]

,
,

[image]

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: how do i share sample data?

Comment: Sounds like a network/cost problem. Cost in this case would not be distance or time, but simply the number of road segments

Comment: Share sample data by uploading to any cloud service and post the link here (best in your initial post)

Comment: I posted a link in the topic. the data contains the more complicated infrastructure

Comment: Don't have access to the data with the link you posted, access is restricted...

Comment: were you able to download the data?

Comment: Yes, did not have time yet to check. not so trivial. Maybe indeed try to ask severyl separate questions for part of the problem. See also comment by @til_b below: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449414/sum-attribute-values-based-on-previous-attribute-value?noredirect=1#comment734125_449419

Answer (score 2):

I suppose lines have an increasing unique id corresponding to the spatial order of the lines, so the leftmoste line with smallest id and then incresing to te next one on the right side etc.

Use this expression to create the sum of all `demand` attribute values with an id <= the id of the current feature:

```
with_variable(
    'id',
    "id",
    eval(
        'sum ("demand", filter:="id"<='  || @id || ')'
    )
)
```

---

If your line layer doesn't have a `demand` attribute, you can modify the expression to get the `demand` value from the point layer:

```
with_variable(
    'id',
    "id",
    eval(
        'sum (overlay_nearest (''point'', "demand")[0], filter:="id"<='  || @id || ')'
    )
)
```

Comment: In this test case , they have  increasing ID's yes. BUT I want to apply it to a more difficult infrastructure where they don't have increasing/decreasing ID's.

Comment: So then maybe an intermediary step would be to create such a (spatially) increasing id. Would be worth asking this as a separate question here as in fact your task inplies two separate problems: 1) create a spatially increasing id, 2) summing the values based on this id.

Comment: You need the increasing IDs or something, but that gets complicated because you need to think about different branches of infeeders. See in the second example image the branches coming from the north that all connect to the east-west running segment, which also has connections from the south. you need to somehow calculate the sums for each branch separately.