# Create a increasing index ID for a branched linestring

Tags: qgis

How do I create a (spatial) increasing index ID for a branched linestring? I want to do this for a distribution problem (screenshot below and hyperlink: [Sum attribute values based on previous attribute value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449414/sum-attribute-values-based-on-previous-attribute-value)).

[image]

Comment: I think you need to clarify the rules to do this. If it is along the line direction you can just use "Points along Geometry".

Comment: The numbering show start from 1 for each new branch? Can you add a drawing showing how they should be numbered? And the data in the drawing to test with

Comment: I edited the image with arrows for direction